# Strip leading, trailing, and double in-between commas from string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am looking for a function that would remove leading, trailing, and double commas in between names in a string, leaving only one comma in between each full name.

Below is an example of what I mean by this, I am trying to get from the left column to the right column.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| , Shane Beau, , Karlene Myles, | Shane Beau, Karlene Myles |
| Lorayne Mica, | Lorayne Mica |
| , Marie Ashton, | Marie Ashton |
| Emmet Rowan, Martha Dave, , Fred Sawyer | Emmet Rowan, Martha Dave, Fred Sawyer |

So far I have tried `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "))," ",",")`, which works in removing the double commas in between the names, but places a comma between the first and last names.

Any insight into how I can tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

replace the spaces with something else, then replace the commas with spaces and trim then replace it all back:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|"),",|"," "),",",""))," ",", "),"|"," ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, your solution seems to work pretty well until it encounters a cell containing "name , , name" (there are spaces in front/behind each comma). But seems like this occurrence was caused by a keying error in the original string and a pretty rare case. Those I can manually fix so thanks for the help!

Comment: Add some more SUBSTITUTES: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","|"),"|,|"," "),",|"," "),","," "))," ",", "),"|"," ")`

Answer (score 0):

Another formula option, include cell A5 containing "name , , name" (there are spaces in front/behind each comma)

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&IF(RIGHT(A2)=",",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),A2)," , ",""),",",", "))
```

[image]